# How can I separate classes into different files?

Tags: java, jcreator

I have a file with two classes and I was asked to separate the second class into a separate file. I have no idea how to do that and I'm wondering if the program will still work. Would I need to put them into the same project or how will I be able to still make the program work?

Comment: I suggest, first you go through [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)

Comment: Shouldn't this be already done when you compile the files by jvm ? Btw, you have not mentioned which language, which IDE, and what OS.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can separate out 2 classes and still they will work fine. Just make sure you import one class in another using import statement.

For instance say you have a java source file named "MyClaas.java" having 2 java classes like below:

File: MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass{
........
........
}

class AnotherClass{
........
........
}
```

All you need to do is move AnotherClass class into a separate source file named with name same as class name ie "AnotherClass.java"(Do not forget to mark class as public in it).

Your final code structure should be something like this.

File: MyClass.java

```
import AnotherClass;
public class MyClass{
private AnotherClass c1=new AnotherClass ();
........
........
}
```

File: AnotherClass.java

```
import MyClass;
public class AnotherClass{
    private MyClass c1=new MyClass();
    ........
    ........
    }
```

You can access methods of class MyClass from AnotherClass using instance variable "c1", like this c1.doSomething();

Answer (score -1):

First of all the community won't be able to help you if you don't post your code or at least your attempts. Also you need to explain your problem.

Anyways as far as i understand your question then just put them into the same project, the program should be able to work and don't forget to import that class into the main class.